# Interface an SPI OLED swtch with a PC

Tags: spi

I'm making a prototype with limited engineering skills, and have the need to integrate a NKK OLED Rocker Switch (SPI interface) with a Windows PC.  I've the development kit that allows me to change the menus and screens to fit, and have purchase a USB HS SPI/I2C/JTAG adapter for this purpose - but I'm stumped.  NKK is a bit weak on literature for grasshoppers as I.  Any direction appreciated.

EDIT  - Thanks for both reply's.  I purchased the individual parts that comprise the Dev 8 kit, to include the switch, controller board, power and cabling.  Placing the pictures, text and such was quite an easy task for me.  My next step is to somehow integrate the button press features into the Advantech ARK-3360L via a USB port.  I chose the FTDI USB t- SPI cable mentioned above to provide that interface, but it appears I was a bit to presumptive IRT the steps required to interface SPI to USB.  It appears that I need to program a "chip", assume this is the IC inside the FTDI cable, to translate the SPI to USB.  But I'm still not sure. Jeff

Comment: Which development kit do you have, and which usb adapter did you buy?

Answer (score 1):

Since your question didn't have any part numbers, I am assuming you are asking about the NKK's IS18WWC1W monochrome OLED Rocker Switch. The Switch datasheet is very short (more of a marketing white paper), but their [Application Notes](http://www.nkkswitches.com/pdf/Application%20Notes%20for%20OLED%20Rocker.pdf) details the Power Initialization, wiring, SPI communications, how to write to the display etc. It is a fairly standard SPI device.

The display data is fairly simple, since it is monochrome (b/w, no grey scale). 96 on/off bits per line, 64 lines.

Comment: Oooh my first unwarranted mute down vote. So helpful.